# awk print two substrings

Tags: awk

here  I have input like this

```
Nov  8 19:32:18 hostname api[-]: {"api_id":"5b4b0977cdfe813c0","app_type":"PRODUCTION","status_code":"200 OK","bytes_received":0,"response_body":"","request_method":"GET","client_id":"","http_user_agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT; Windows NT 10.0; en-US) WindowsPowerShell/5.1.17134.228","billing":{"amount":0,"provider":"none","currency":"USD","model":"free","trial_period_days":0},"datetime":"2018-11-08T19:32:18.036Z","time_to_serve_request":31,"uri_path":"/abc/abc","request_protocol":"https","request_method":"POST","http_host":"localhost:700","request_uri":"/_bulk","http_x_forwarded_server":"locahost.com","content_type":"text/plain","http_x_global_transaction_id":"8f4202d3cf31","http_x_forwarded_host":"analytics.com","http_x_forwarded_for":"1.1.6.3","request_path":"/_bulk","http_organization":"admin","http_x_client_ip":"127.0.0.1","content_length":"2738"},"catalog_name":"test","immediate_client_ip":"1.1.6.3","debug":[],"rateLimit":{"rate-limit":{"limit":"-1","count":"-1"},"rate-limit-1":{"limit":"-1","count":"-1"},"rate-limit-2":{"limit":"-1","count":"-1"},"per-minute":{"limit":"-1","count":"-1"}},"api_version":"1.0.0","bytes_sent":217,"product_name":"N/A","plan_name":"N/A","tags":["_geoip_lookup_failure"],"catalog_id":"5ab7d1ebe4b0ad8c50045165","gateway_geoip":{},"app_name":"N/A","@timestamp":"2018-11-08T19:32:18.118Z","request_body":"","org_id":"5aaf1467e4b0ad8c500450f3","api_name":"productapi","resource_id":"abc","plan_id":"","query_string":[]}
```

I would like to print two values from this input i.e `status_code`  and `api_name`

in this one `"status_code":"200 OK"` and  `"api_name":"productapi"`

can we print like `200  productapi`  using either `awk` or a shell script ?

Comment: This looks like a JSON document in a log file (why is a log file the input you are working with?), but the JSON is broken. If you had the complete JSON document it would be easy to use `jq` on the pre-processed logfile data to get the strings you want.

Comment: thank you , your are correct , this JSON is broken , I just edited  to remove some my enviormnet specticf values and updated  here with out validation, My actual requirement is want to parse this json  syslog and load  some parameters in prometheus  time servies database ,, to parse and load this syslog data I thought of using grok exporter , but   I could not do that through count monitors , if you have any other options to parse and load data please let me know,

Answer (score 0):

`sed` OK? Try

```
$ sed  's/^.*status_code":"//; s/ .*api_name":"/ /; s/".*$//' file
200 productapi
```

Answer (score 0):

Using AWK :

```
awk -F '[ "]' '{gsub(/.*status_code":"|OK".*api_name":"/,""); print $1" "$2}' fileName

200 productapi
```